# Relationship between Keras, Lasagne, Block and Theano?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, theano, keras

What's the relationship between Keras, Lasagne, Block and Theano? The references for the former say they are "built on top" of Theano but it also seems like Theano can be used by itself for running Neural Networks. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are built on top, this does not mean theano cannot be used for the same purpose. If something is built on top it means that it is something using theano to achieve the goal. Bulting on top of something simply aims at providing some functionality in an easier way. And using Keras or Lasagne is way simpler to develop NNs then pure Theano (which was just side, research project in Montreal to support development of pylearn)

Comment: Would you say this is true: for a given task it might take 5-10+ lines of code in Theano and possibly a lot of specification of parameters. Keras builds wrapper functions that can accomplish the same thing by limiting or setting as default a lot of specifications so the user doesn't have to see it. In addition, Theano may make use of lower-level scripting languages to get added efficiency, whereas Keras/Lasagne don't pay attention to that, and just depend on Theano to do it for them?

Comment: This captures one of many properties of these libraries. It seems that you are trying to write some blog post, or maybe homework/thesis assignment - if this is the case you should dive deeper into actual capabilities of each library, you will not be able to sum up any of these in three sentences. sorry.

Comment: Not writing a paper. Just trying to make sense of things... I posted a separate question that addressed the larger question but that didn't go over too well...http://stackoverflow.com/q/37082385/3633522

Comment: SO is about small questions, problems, not achieving comprehensive tutorial to something (and this is more or less what you asked for in this second question), so it will probably get more downvotes overtime (and probably end up closed).

Comment: Theano is not just a side research project to support pylearn; pylearn is no even being developed now.